# How can I have a doctest test that the result includes some text, rather than an exact match?

Tags: python, doctest

I understand that I can write a doctest like:

```
def foo():
    """
    >>> foo()
    'abc'
    """
    return 'abc'
```

However, what if my function is fetching a large HTML file?  I don't want to have to put the entire contents of the returned string into the doctest.  Instead I just want to be able to assert that the returned HTML includes an expected bit, something like:

```
"<title>The Right Page</title>" in returnedValue
```

Is this possible in doctests, or do I need a real unit test to check this?

Comment: What you write after the `>>> ` is a code expression that `doctest` will evaluate, and what you write on the next line is an expectation for the `repr` of the evaluated result. Can you think of an expression that will have one specific result if the HTML contains what it should, and a different result otherwise? (Hint: it is already in the question.) Knowing this, is it clear how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can simply check if the result of the comparison is `True`.

```
"""
>>> "<title>The Right Page</title>" in foo()
True
"""
```